# Not able to open pop up in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am not able to open a pop up window. Below is my code. Let me know where i am doing wrong

**XAML code**

```
      <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding BankNameList}" x:Name="lstvw">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource HyperLinkButtonStyle}" Content="{Binding}" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OpenPopup, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Popup x:Name="Popup" IsOpen="{Binding Open}" StaysOpen="True" Placement="Bottom" >
                <Grid Background="Blue" Width="200" Height="100">
                    <TextBlock Text ="Hello"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

**ViewModel Code**

```
    private bool open;
    public bool Open
    {
        get { return open; }
        set
        {
            open = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Open");
        }
    }
    public ICommand OpenPopup { get { return new RelayCommand(s => ShowPopup()); } }

    public void ShowPopup()
    {
        Open = true;
    }
```

Comment: How did you setup the Viewmodel to the View?

Comment: DataContext = new ViewModel() in xaml.cs

Comment: Are you able to hit a breakpoint in the `ShowPopup` method? If yes, is the `Open` getter called after setting it's value to true? Any binding errors in the VS output window?

Comment: yes i am able to hit showpopup method and open value changing to true...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.placement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Since you don't really post the XAML for the control that these controls are children of, it's hard to tell what is going on.

Anyways, lets say the StackPanel containing the Popup is all the way at the bottom of the control, its possible that the popup is popping up behind the Windows task bar, or maybe won't leave the bounds of the window/control it is contained in. Maybe try a different Placement or setting a placement target.  Use Snoop to inspect the Popup after the button is clicked to see if its IsOpen property is set to true.

The only other thing I can think of is your DataContext is wrong.  Is `Open` in the same ViewModel as `BankNameList`? If not, it should be.

**Edit**

I will assume that your DataContext isn't correct.  I created a sample project, here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/11003217).

Everything seemed to be working for me.  I saw a popup in the top-left corner of the window.  I put a toggle is ShowPopup so the popup toggled every time I clicked a button.

Comment: thanks 4 reply... 'Open' is in same view model as BankNameList

Comment: Thank you very much ... wasted my whole day because of one silly mistake. I forgot to inherit INotifyPropertyChanged interface.... :P